# How to read and write code output into a text file line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, my list looks like this from my text file:

```
1,2.12,3.123
```

Then it prints this to my output text file (decimal places from each number):

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
```

However, if my list from my text file is like this:

```
1,2.12,3.123
1,1.00
```

Then it prints this to my output text file:

```
Line 1: Line 2:   INVALID 
VALID
INVALID
Line 3: Line 4:   INVALID
VALID
INVALID
```

How do I get it to print this to my output text file:

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
LINE 2: INVALID VALID
```

I tried to add an index = index +1 so it can add 1 to every line.

```
from functools import reduce
res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
for line in open("file.txt"):  # read file line-by-line
        carrera = ''
        index = index +1       # Count lines that contain what the command wants
        print("Line {}: ".format(index))
        baconFile.write("Line {}:  ".format(index))

    with open('file.txt') as file:
        number_list = file.readline().strip().split(',')
        for line in number_list:
            if len(line.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                # res += 1
##              print("VALID")

                carrera = valid_string 
            if len(line.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                #res += 1
                carrera = invalid_string  

            print (carrera)
            baconFile.write(carrera + " ")
# print(res)
baconFile.close()
```

Expected:

```
Line 1: INVALID VALID INVALID
LINE 2: INVALID VALID
```

Actual:

```
Line 1: Line 2:   INVALID 
    VALID
    INVALID
    Line 3: Line 4:   INVALID
    VALID
    INVALID
```

Comment: You need to format the string before writing. Also, is there a reason to open the same file in a `for` loop?

Comment: Read the file in with enumeration, `with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f: for number, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):` This will give you the line number and read line by line. Thought this might be useful.

Comment: @mad_ I just noticed the additional for in the loop. What do you mean format the string? So I should .format(carrera) at the end or...?

Comment: @Slashx43 If opening the file in a loop is not intentional then can you update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications for formatting:

```
res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        index = index +1
        o = "Line {}: ".format(index)
        number_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for x in number_list:
            if len(x.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                o += valid_string + " "
            if len(x.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                o += invalid_string + " "

        print(o)
        baconFile.write(o + "\n")
baconFile.close()
```

EDIT: accidentally left the 'carrera' variable there, thought I might edit it out, since it no longer serves a purpose

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each line in a file with `for line in file`, and print without a newline with `print('...', end='')`. Don't `open()` it twice.

```
res = 0
outfile = "output2.txt"
baconFile = open(outfile,"wt")
index = 0
invalid_string = "INVALID"
valid_string = "VALID"
index = 1
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print("Line {}: ".format(index), end='')
        baconFile.write("Line {}:  ".format(index))
        number_list = line.strip().split(',')
        for number in number_list:
            if len(number.split('.')[-1]) == 2:
                #res += 1
##              print("VALID")

                carrera = valid_string 
            if len(number.split('.')[-1]) != 2:
                #res += 1
                carrera = invalid_string  

            print (carrera, end='')
            baconFile.write(carrera + " ")
        print('\n', end='')
        baconFile.write('\n')
        index += 1
```

(To other answerers: I avoid `enumerate` because the code already has `index` in it.)

Comment: This does not write to new line each time.

Comment: It does write to new line each time but for your code it starts at Line 0: and not at Line 1: . Everything else works fine